# typescript use keys as restriction for strings

Tags: typescript

I have the following interface:

```
interface Address {
   street: string
   town: string
   country: string
}
```

I want a function to accept a key parameter that has to be one of three strings:

```
function useKey(key: "street" | "town" | "country") {
}
```

Can I somehow generate the type for the key parameter from the interface?

Comment: [Index Types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typescript has the `keyof` type operator for this exact specific case:

```
function useKey(key: keyof Address ) {
}
```

This will give you all the public keys of a type in a union.

You can use type queries to even get to the type of the filed:

```
function getValue<K extends keyof Address>(key: K): Address[K]{
     //...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`keyof`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#keyof-and-lookup-types) operator:

```
type AddressKey = keyof Address
```